# JavaScript, I can't generate alert boxes on intentionally improper inputs

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, alert

I'm very new, only a few weeks into the JavaScript portion of the class I'm taking.
I can't get my alert boxes to generate for improper inputs on my input forms.
What mistake am I making?
I'm hoping to identify this first issue before even getting into the calculations needed and the output form because hopefully nipping this in the bud will add clarity to how I'm going to make my output work.

```js
function rootCal(form) {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").valueAsNumber;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").valueAsNumber;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").valueAsNumber;
  var aOk = a.checkValidity();
  var bOk = b.checkValidity();
  var cOk = c.checkValidity();
  if (!form.checkValidity()) {

    if (((!aOk) || (a == 0)) && (bOk) && (cOk)) {
      alert(
        "localhost:8950 says:/n" +
        "invalid entry for a. Must be a non-zero integer between -99 and +99."
      );
    } else if ((aOk && a !== 0) && (!bOk) && (cOk)) {
      alert(
        "localhost:8950 says:\n" +
        "invalid entry for b. Must be an integer between -99 and +99."
      );
    } else if ((aOk && a !== 0) && (bOk) && (!cOk)) {
      alert(
        "localhost:8950 says:\n" +
        "invalid entry for c. Must be an integer between -99 and +99."
      );
    } else if (((!aOk) || (a == 0)) && (!bOk) && (cOk)) {
      alert(
        "localhost:8950 says:\n" +
        "invalid entry for a. Must be a non-zero integer between -99 and +99.<br>\n" +
        "invalid entry for b. Must be an integer between -99 and +99."
      );
    } else if (((!aOk) || (a == 0)) && (bOk) && (!cOk)) {
      alert(
        "localhost:8950 says:\n" +
        "invalid entry for a. Must be a non-zero integer between -99 and +99.<br>\n" +
        "invalid entry for c. Must be an integer between -99 and +99."
      );
    } else if (((aOk) || (a !== 0)) && (!bOk) && (!cOk)) {
      alert(
        "localhost:8950 says:\n" +
        "invalid entry for b. Must be an integer between -99 and +99.<br>\n" +
        "invalid entry for c. Must be an integer between -99 and +99."
      );
    } else if (((!aOk) || (a == 0)) && (!bOk) && (!cOk)) {
      alert(
        "localhost:8950 says:\n" +
        "invalid entry for a. Must be a non-zero integer between -99 and +99.\n" +
        "invalid entry for b. Must be an integer between -99 and +99.\n" +
        "invalid entry for c. Must be an integer between -99 and +99."
      );
    }
  } else {
    if ((b ** 2) < (4 * a * c)) {
      ;
    } else if ((b ** 2) == (4 * a * c)) {
      ;
    } else if ((b ** 2) > (4 * a * c)) {
      ;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Quadratic Equation Roots Calculator</h1>
  <p>
    This web page finds the roots of a polynomial equation of the following form: <br>
    <em>ax<sup>2</sup>+bx+c=0</em>
    <br><br>
    <em>a, b,</em> and <em>c</em> must be integers between <em>-99</em> and <em>+99,</em> and <em>a</em> must be non-zero.
  </p>
  <form id="roots-input">
    <label for="a">a:</label>
    <input id="a" class="number" type="number" min="-99" max="99" step="1" required>
    <label for="b">&nbsp;b:</label>
    <input id="b" class="number" type="number" min="-99" max="99" step="1" required>
    <label for="c">&nbsp;c:</label>
    <input id="c" class="number" type="number" min="-99" max="99" step="1" required>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="button" class="calculator" form="roots-input" value="Calculate roots" onclick="rootCal(this.form)">
    <br><br>
    <output id="calculated-root" form="roots-input"></output>
  </div>
</article>
```

I've updated and tried to clean up the parentheses and the else if syntax issue. I still can't generate any alert boxes, does the final else of the calculations need to be completed to even generate the alert box?

Comment: `a.checkValidity()` is not a function. What are you intending to do here?

Comment: @asynAwaitFetch I'm trying to make sure that the inputs that are entered fit the min/max constraints as well as the step constraint to be an integer. I was under the impression .checkValidity() was what you typed to check that an input fits the constraints?  how would I properly do this, I want to make sure A is non-zero, and A,B,C are all integers between -99 - +99 then after clicking calculate root and one of the inputs are improper an alert box will pop up detailing what is invalid and what it should be

Comment: `checkValidity()` is a method of the input element. But you set `a` to the value of the input, not the element itself.

Comment: Here: `var a = document.getElementById("a").valueAsNumber;`

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much, this solved it. I had no idea adding the .valueAsNumber would break that like that. Gettting rid of that, finally I can get the alert box to show up

Comment: But you'll need to change `a == 0` to `a.valueAsNumber == 0`

Comment: @Barmar I actually was just encountering that issue, thankful that you posted this here in followup. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried changing the way you do your if conditions?

You have too much parenthesis there.

Instead of if (((!aOk) || (a == 0)) && (bOk) && (cOk))
Try if (!aOk || a == 0 && bOk && cOk6)

Comment: Hello! Your suggested answer is not a fix to the problem described in the question. Suggesting a cosmetic change to the code may be valuable, but probably belongs in the comments. Subjectively, I do not feel your suggested conditional is more readable than the conditional you are suggesting to change, though I do agree that the conditional is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: Hey sorry, im very new to stack overflow, i will take your advice very kindly and not make that mistake again. Thanks

Comment: No worries, I just thought it might be useful to understand why your answer might be recieving downvotes. Happy coding!